# Android pass Edit Text data onChange from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a main activity with a heading and a search field (edit text), I want to be able to search and the results are immediately shown in the fragment, like an onChange instead of waiting for the user to click a button to filter results. (which is in the activity).

I can get it working if I include the Edit Text in my fragment too, but I don't want it that way for design purposes, I'd like to retrieve the user values as they are typed from the activity, and get them in my fragment to filter results

I've tried Bundles but could not get it working, and also not sure If i could use Bundles to get the results as they are being input.

Here's a screenshot to help understand better
[image: The top heading with the Edit Text is the activity, the Recycler View etc are part of a fragment]

Comment: You can have the EditText in the MainActivity and still use the onTextChanged listener. I would suggest using a ViewModel to track state changes, Activities and Fragments should only subscribe to the ViewModel to present such state. More info about ViewModel: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it happen using ViewModel + MVVM architecture.

**MainActivity:**

```kotlin
binding.editText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        viewModel.updateSearchText(s)
    }
})
```

**ViewModel:**

```kotlin
private val _searchText = MutableLiveData<Editable?>()
val searchText: LiveData<Editable?> get() = _searchText

fun updateSearchText(text: Editable?) {
    _searchText.value = s
}
```

**Fragment:**

```kotlin
searchText.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    // TODO: handle the searched query using [it] keyword.
}
```

If you don't know what View Model is or how to implement it, use the official Google tutorial: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-viewmodel

Comment: Probably a good idea to show how to get the activity view model in the fragment example code for completeness and do `model.searchText.observe(...`

Comment: Thanks for the response, forgot to mention I'm using Java so this looks foreign to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this (besides using an Android ViewModel) is use the [Fragment Result API](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragments).

For instance, if you place the `EditText` into a fragment (let's call it `QueryFragment`), you can get the result of the `QueryFragment` in your `SearchResults` fragment like so:

```kotlin
// In QueryFragment


editText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        setFragmentResult("searchQueryRequestKey", bundleOf("searchQuery" to s.toString()))
    }
})
```

```kotlin
// In SearchResultsFragment

    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Retrieve the searched string from QueryFragment

        // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
        setFragmentResultListener("searchQueryRequestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
    
            val searchQuery = bundle.getString("searchQuery")

            // Perform the search using the searchQuery and display the search results
    }
}
```